# Accuracy/Quality of financial data: revised financials or historical financials?

Tags: data, historical-data, valuation, investing, analysis

I am currently working on calculating financial metrics, particularly Free Cash Flow to Equity (FCFE) etc., for investment analysis.

In the context of financial analysis, I'm wondering which set of data is generally considered more preferable for my purpose: the restated financials reflecting the most recent adjustments (for a given year), or the historical financials originally filed at that year?

**Example: When seeking the **Net cash provided by operating activities** for the year **2020** for **Paypal**, there are two options:**

(Historical) Reporting date: 2020-12-31;   Result:  5,854 millions

(Most recent) Reporting date: 2022-12-31;   Result: 6,219 millions

**Another Example: EXXON MOBIL - Reductions in short-term debt for 2020**

(Historical) Reporting date: 2020-12-31;   Result:  (1,703) millions

(Most recent) Reporting date: 2022-12-31;   Result: (28,742) millions

Which of the two should one consider in regards to quality of data (in a similar sense as "Quality of earnings")?

If anyone has insights or experiences in this area, could you please share your perspective on whether it's wiser to base calculations on the most recent financials for a given year or stick to the historical financials? Any considerations or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Sources:
(Paypal, 2022 and 2020)

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1633917/000163391723000033/pypl-20221231.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1633917/000163391721000018/pypl-20201231.htm

(Exxon, 2022 and 2020)

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/34088/000003408823000020/xom-20221231.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/34088/000003408821000012/xom-20201231.htm

Comment: If you are making an investment decision as of now, then the current ("most recent") data is probably best. But if you are "backtesting" an investment strategy, i.e. checking how you would have done if you had made investment decisions at predetermined points in the past, then it is very important to use "point in time" data, that is the data  that was available at the time the hypothetical decision was being considered. This complicates the backtesting process considerably but is essential for accuracy.